# Show popup on hover rather than on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found a tutorial on adding popup boxes but want the box to appear on hover rather than on click. How can I alter this code to do that?

```
function div_show() {
  document.getElementById('abc').style.display = "block";
}

function deselect(e) {
  $('.pop').slideFadeToggle(function() {
    e.removeClass('selected');
  });
}

$(function() {
  $('#youtube').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
      deselect($(this));
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('selected');
      $('.pop').slideFadeToggle();
    }
    return false;
  });

  $('.close').on('click', function() {
    deselect($('#youtube'));
    return false;
  });
});

$.fn.slideFadeToggle = function(easing, callback) {
  return this.animate({
    opacity: 'toggle'
  }, 'fast', easing, callback);
};
```

Comment: Look at replacing the click events with 'mouseover' and 'mouseout'. Replace the first 'click' with 'mouseover' and the second 'click' with mouseout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`hover()`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) method in jQuery:

```
$("#youtube").hover(function(){
    $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
    }, function(){
    $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
});
```

The first function is the method that will execute when the user's mouse enters, and the second function will be fired when the user's mouse leaves the element.

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/2hLjs4qt/

Comment: This works great. Thank you. Is there any way to disable the animation also?

Comment: @Whisetter46 - no problem, please accept this is as the answer.  To disable the animation you could probably remove the line: `$('.pop').slideFadeToggle();`

Comment: @Whisetter46 - To stop the animation, inside `deselect` function add `$(this).stop()` or `$('.pop').stop()`